# Matching by column within a specified range in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of arrays that I want to match to a seperate set of arrays I have, within a certain range. Example code bloew:

```
arr1_1 = np.array([468.12, 30.4, 879.74])
arr1_2 = np.array([351.20, 84.98, 514.45])
arr1_3 = np.array([21.456, 89.56, 69.45])

array_1 = np.column_stack ((arr1_1, arr1_2, arr1_3))

arr2_1 = np.array([879.12, 48.4, 212.47...])
arr2_2 = np.array([389.06, 80.91, 87.98...])
arr2_3 = np.array([224.566, 98.35, 657.30..])

array_2 = np.column_stack ((arr2_1, arr2_2, arr2_3))
```

The second set of arrays are much larger than the first. Is there any way to match the second set to the first, by column, within a specific range? i.e any rows from  array_2 where the second columns value (array2_2) is within ±5 of array1_2 in array_1? In this examply my ideal output would be

```
array_match = ([48.4, 80.91, 98.35])
```

(because 80.91 is within 5 of 84.98)

Comment: Why 48.4 or 98.35?

Comment: `(because 80.91 is within 5 of 84.98)` but the other 2 examples are not

Comment: They're column stacked, as each row contains information on a specific object. So 80.91 is within 5 of 84.98, and it would return all the numbers in the row that it is in.